# vim :changes how to go to a specific line

Tags: vim, modifier

According to the help's changes in vim, i type :3g; to go to line 3 but that don't work and it leave the pane changes.

what are the way to go to a specific line ?

thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go to a specific line in changes list, you need to close the changes list first, then use `g;` to go previous change or use `g,` to go next change.

`3g;` equals to execute `g;` 3 times, if you want to go to specific line you need to know your current position which indicated by `>`, then go up `n` line using `ng;` and go down `n` line using `ng,`.

Comment: You are 100% right about those commands but the OP is asking about the changelist: `:help :change`.

Comment: oops, I misunderstanded the question

Comment: I discovered gundo who are exactly what i'm looking for https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim/blob/master/README.markdown

Answer (score 1):

No, `:help :changes` doesn't tell you to do `:3g;`.

It's `3g;`, *in normal mode*.

Comment: When i type 3g; un normal mode it's automaticaly close the pane changes on the "3" and nothing changes.

Comment: You are supposed to press `<CR>` to close the list and then press `ng;` to jump to change `n`.

Comment: okay but when i do that , it simply move to the specific line but the change is not recovered. is it normal ? sorry i'm a beginner in vim

Comment: Yes, you jump to the location where the change happened but the change itself is not reversed. Are you looking for `:help undolist`?